# iOS Push with Cloud Page sent from Journey Builder has incorrect type

Tags: journeybuilder, ios, cloudpage

I'm sending a push notification via **Journey Builder**, I add a Push Notification Activity and in the Message Definition, I'm setting the Open Behaviour as **Go to CloudPage** and I select one from the menu.

[image]

I then proceed to Activate the Journey to receive the push notification, which I do.

In the app, the delegate callback

```
- (void)sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *)url type:(NSString *)type
```

is called with type **SFMCURLTypeOpenDirect** and not the expected **SFMCURLTypeCloudPage**.

Why is that? If I send a push from Mobile Push tool instead with the same behaviour of opening a Cloud Page, I get the correct type (**SFMCURLTypeCloudPage**).

iOS 12
MarketingCLoudSDK 6.2.2

Comment: Sorry for not answering the question but I have to ask the exact steps you took to reproduce the issue. Did you select 'Go to CloudPage' option from the beginning?
Or did you happen to select any other options such as 'Go to App URL' or 'Go to Web URL' before selecting the CloudPage option? We're trying to identify what's exactly happening with the Open Behavior dropdown.

Comment: I selected 'Go to CloudPage' from the beginning, but in other attempts I did start with other options as well.. but the result is the same, I always get the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input!
We've identified the issue and currently working on the fix.
We're planning to deploy the fix as soon as possible. It will be deployed by the next couple of weeks.
We will let you know once the release date for the fix is confirmed.

Comment: Hi Inhwan, welcome to SFSE! Can you please **[edit]** this post to clarify who you mean by "we"?